# Write a value in specific row & column of csv in vb6

Tags: arrays, parsing, csv, vb6

I have some code to search for a value from a csv.

I want to search for a value, and then when I find the exact value, 
I will update the field to indicate that I already found this as for reference, please see below:

```
 For R = 0 To num_rows
    If Len(lines(R)) > 0 Then
        one_line = Split(lines(R), ",")
        For C = 0 To num_cols
            the_array(R, C) = one_line(C)

                'Check Serial from List
                If the_array(R, 3) = strCode Then

                readCsv = the_array(R, 3) 'return serial from list
                strTestcnt = the_array(R, 1) 'retry count
                strProcess = the_array(R, 2) 'process/station

         '--->>> in this part I'd like to add a new value on the_array(R, 4) with the value "1"
         '--->>> and save it on the csv file, how can i do this?
         '--->>> I open the csv file using "fnum = FreeFile"
                "Open file_name For Input As fnum"


                Exit Function
                End If
        Next C
    End If
 Next R
```

maybe you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing can be far easier to work with using a Variant containing an array of arrays.

```
Private Sub CsvUpdate(ByVal Code As String)
    Dim F As Integer
    Dim RowData As String
    Dim RowCols() As String
    Dim NewCol As Long
    Dim CsvRows As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    F = FreeFile(0)
    Open "old.csv" For Input As #F
    ReDim CsvRows(0)
    Do Until EOF(F)
        Line Input #F, RowData
        RowCols = Split(RowData, ",")
        If NewCol = 0 Then NewCol = UBound(RowCols) + 1
        ReDim Preserve RowCols(NewCol) 'Add new column.
        ReDim Preserve CsvRows(R) 'Add new row.
        CsvRows(R) = RowCols 'Assign columns to row.
        R = R + 1
    Loop
    Close #F

    For R = 0 To UBound(CsvRows)
        If Trim$(CsvRows(R)(3)) = Code Then
            'Do something....
            CsvRows(R)(NewCol) = "1" 'Mark it "processed"
        Else
            CsvRows(R)(NewCol) = "0" 'Mark it "not processed"
                                     'or just leave null.
        End If
    Next

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "new.csv"
    On Error GoTo 0
    F = FreeFile(0)
    Open "new.csv" For Output As #F
    For R = 0 To UBound(CsvRows)
        Print #F, Join$(CsvRows(R), ",")
    Next
    Close #F
End Sub
```